# Saving Type 1 eps with bold font with matplotlib

Tags: fonts, matplotlib

I am generating eps files with Type 1 with `matplotlib` with this command

```
       matplotlib.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
       matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
       matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

However, it seems that I can't have any bold font. For example if I do

```
       font= FontProperties()
       font.set_weight('black')

       text(0.7, 0.95,'my text',fontproperties=font)
```

the text is not bold at all. Have you ever come across this problem?